# test connection with OData without getting any data

Tags: java, http, odata, odata4j

I was wondering, is there some way to get just the response from OData server, preferably with odata4j client, without any particular data actually being sent? I can request the server for metadata, but that's kind of wasteful, since it sends lot of data.

I want to send request and get response that would tell me if authorisation is correct and whether the server generally responds correctly, but I don't want to ask for any particular data. I know I could ask for something random, that's not very elegant though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the HTTP [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) method.